# Check mounted in provider?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

When I use `Provider` how I can check `!mounted` ?

For example if widget removed from tree while asynchronous platform message in flight I not want update widget.

Or is `Provider` handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: [i think this answer is what you are looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58571942/9849562)